# No overload for 'button1_Click' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Tags: c#

I have this bit of code:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
 {
     public partial class Form1 : Form
     {
         public Form1()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
         }
         public class vars
         {
             public static int x = 250;
             public static int y = 250;
         }
         private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             button1.Visible = false;
             Pen main = new Pen(Color.Black);
             this.Graphics.DrawRectangle(main, vars.x, vars.y, 2, 2);
             while (true)
             {

             }
         }
      }
 }
```

But i keep getting an annoying error (No overload for 'button1_Click' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler') that I don't know how to approach. Ive been searching online and trouble shooting for a while, and have not found any answers. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Where did `PaintEventArgs g` come from?

Comment: You have three arguments, not two. Remove the middle one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the `PaintEventArgs g` part of your code. The method that is attached to an event must match the "pattern" for the event.

Declare the vars outside of your own class, unless you will need them outside of Form1. Its just unnecessary.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int x = 250;
        int y = 250;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
            button1.Visible = false;
            Pen main = new Pen(Color.Black);
            this.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle(main, vars.x, vars.y, 2, 2);
       }
    }
}
```

That should work!

Comment: Okay your edit is great, but what do you mean by set the value of g? :/

Comment: Like, are you trying to draw the rectangle on the Form? or the Button? Where was the Graphics coming from?

Comment: oh i see an error i made in the code ^^ i want to draw it in the form, when the button gets pressed, but thats something i could fix.

Comment: oh and g represents PaintEventArgs

Comment: Error 13 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1' does not contain a definition for 'Graphics' and no extension method 'Graphics' accepting a first argument of type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 28 18 WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: Ahh. Have you referenced System.Drawing? Add a reference to that assembly.

Comment: do you mean said 'using System.Drawing' at the begining of the file? if so then yes i have

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the error on my computer. I'd say, make sure you copied the code exactly.

Comment: ah. I don't think that you saw one of my updates.
Put this code in:
this.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle(main, vars.x, vars.y, 2, 2);

Comment: instead of this.Graphics.DrawRectangle(main, vars.x, vars.y, 2, 2);

Comment: Lol i did something stupid but it worked. I deleted the line that was giving me an error and now it works, but i think your code got rid of my original error :) if i could upvote posts i would

Comment: I'm glad it worked. If you feel so inclined, you can always "accept the answer" by pressing the check mark underneath the arrows used to upvote and downvote. Cheers!